# Cannot send my output from views.py to template in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, render

what my application does is capture live images and extract some values using google vision ocr.
I get data from an external python script and i want to show the output in html text field.

here is my views.py template

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import TemperatureRecordsF, TemperatureRecordC , BloodPressureRecord , SPO2Levels
import sys
import base64
from PIL import Image
from subprocess import run, PIPE


def button(request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    return render(request,'capturr1.html',)

def external(request, *args, **kwargs):

    request_getdata = request.POST.get('img64',None)
    selected_radio = request.POST.get('radio_seleect',None)
    print(selected_radio)

    # print(request_getdata)
   
    headed, encoded = request_getdata.split(",",1)
    data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    
    
    with open("D:/dev/django/src/OCR/media/image.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
    path = 'D:/dev/django/src/OCR/media/image.png'
    out = run([sys.executable,'D://dev//django//src//OCR//detect_text.py',path],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    print(out.stdout)

    context = {
        'output' : out.stdout
    }
    
    return render(request,'capturr1.html',context)
```

Here is my template capturr1.html

```
<form class="contentarea" action="/external" method="POST" id="capture" name="capture">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Temperature °F</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Temperature °C</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Blood Pressure</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio4">Oxygen Saturation Levels</label><br>
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video><br>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" name="savebutton"/>
    <input type="text" />{{ output }}
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: none;"><br>
    </canvas>
    <div class="output">
        <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box."><br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my ajax request. I'm sending my canvas image data and selected radio button values to django.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#capture").submit(function(event) {
                    var radio_select = document.capture.inlineRadioOptions.value;
                    console.log(radio_select)

                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'external',
                        data: {
                            'img64': photo.src,
                            'radio_seleect': radio_select


                        }
                    }).done(function() {
                        console.log('sent');


                    });

                });
            });
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Not getting any errors, context is not showing in the html template

Comment: `print(out.stdout)` is this printing some value?

Comment: Yes . It will be printed on the console

Comment: Did you try to use the debug mode in both browser and python to see what is done in each?

Comment: Found no issues while debugging

Comment: I want out.stdout to be displayed on my html. I think django is not rendering after ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your *urlpatterns* looks like this:
`path('external/', views.external, name='ext_data')`

```py
if request.is_ajax():
    if out is not None:
        return JsonResponse({'output':out.stdout})
```

on the js side

```js
$.ajax({
  ... ...
  url: '/external/',
  ... ...
}).done(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
);
```

check if it works..